# Make javascript use the directory it's in

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small script called foo.js in a folder called test where the **location of the directory is unknown**:

```
$.post("bar.php");
```

It's used by two different html files, one at /test/index.html:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

The other at /test/index.html:

```
<script src="../foo.js"></script>
```

When I run the script from /index.html, it works fine and bar.php is called. But when I call it from /subdirectory/index.html, javascript tells me that the resource (bar.php) can't be found. However if I copy and paste bar.php into /subdirectory, it works.

Is there a way to have javascript use the directory the script is located at (in this case, test), instead of using whatever directory it was originally called from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a path relative to your domain, by starting it with `/`:

```
$.post("/bar.php");
```

This way it doesn't matter where the script is, or where the HTML file that called it is, only the location of `bar.php` matters. You should also probably include `foo.js` the same way:

```
<script src="/foo.js"></script>
```

That will work in both files `/index.html` and `/subdirectory/index.html`.

**Edit**: To actually find out where your script is located, relative to the current page, you can use this:

```
(function(){
  var myDirectory = (function(){
    var script = document.currentScript || // SHIM
      (function(){
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
      })();

    var src = script.getAttribute('src');
    return src.substr(0, src.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/';
  })();


  // The rest of your script here, then, wherever you make the post request:
       $.post(myDirectory + "bar.php");

})();
```

Comment: Whoops, I should clarify, root is an unknown folder and I can't use absolute paths, is there still a way to find the position?

Comment: @Luke I've updated it with a way for a script to get the path to itself relative to the current page, which is what your `$.post` request is also relative to, so that should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Try `/bar.php`

You need to use relative paths